# Getting decryption key from a public hash

Tags: encryption, hash, md5

I am working on a problem where I'm told that I have to get the decryption key from a public hash. I know that the hash is: "82F95E39242F17CDF2DFAB502713BAF9" and that the decryption key should be short.
Also, I know that the FINAL decryption key should look like: "[decryption-key]dmEgcHVwYSBrZWx5".

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Try base64 decoding dmEgcHVwYSBrZWx5. This question doesn't really have enough context or details to answer beyond guessing.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk that part can be decoded apparently but I don't know what to do with that hash.

Comment: You cannot get any information from a hash as hashes by their very definition are irreversible. Hashes can only be used to verify they are equal to another hash. And you certainly cannot get a decryption key from hash. This sounds like a trick question.